# Set node version for non node web role

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, gruntjs

i have written an SPA which uses Grunt tasks to build itself from the source code into a `dist` directory.

I want to host this on azure to keep everything in one PaaS.

If i send the prebuilt `dist` folder to azure and add a .deploments task to move it into the `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` folder everything works fine. However i want to just keep source code in GitHub and have the application built at deployment time using the existing Grunt tasks.

I have added a .deployment file with the following command

```
[config]
command = npm install
```

Which sucessfully triggers my npm install, and then the post install script

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt build"
},
```

which will use the local copy of grunt-cli (i don't like this but it works), however i get an error because the version of node being used is 0.6.20 and Grunt requires greater than 0.8

I have set my engine param in the package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.4"
},
```

But no luck :(

I have a feeling that the engine param is ignored because a `node` application is not being found. Which is correct as i want azure to serve my files for me without using a node http server.

Is there a way to target another Node binary or specifically set the version of node for my website even if it is not "using" node as it were?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: are you using `Web Role` (i.e. Cloud Service) or `Azure Web Site` (i.e. Azure Web Sites)?

Comment: @astaykov im using an Azure Web Site. Ive tried messing around with a lot of options but im coming to the conclusion that i will need to make my own "build server" which is said as it seems like major overkill

Answer (score 0):

Using your example of pushing a local copy of grunt-cli to an Azure Web Site I was able to get azure to run grunt after a build and before a deploy.  I am using .net with a post-build event, but that shouldn't really matter because the whole issue is whether azure will run grunt.  I have

```
grunt version 0.4.1
```

and

```
grunt-cli version 0.1.9
```

deploying with my application and am calling

```
npm install
my/path/to/grunt-cli/grunt
```

According to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/specifying-a-node-version/ the current default version of node installed is 0.6.20, but this approach still worked for me.

Comment: Glad your up and running. i should have written back here. The problem is that the later versions of grunt require node > 0.8. We eventually solved our problem with a build server. im not particularly happy with the solution (feels a bit of overkill) but its working.

Comment: By later do you mean older?  I'm on the current latest stable version of grunt 0.4.1 and I have an azure website.  Glad you found a solution, just wanted to point out that it is working so it might save you some $$